# Illustrator outline text, stroke offset creates "holes" in some letters

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I need to create white text over many pictures, the text must be editable so I can't use "create outline" (convert to curves).

The text must have a black outline for readability because many pictures have white areas so it must have contrast.

I went to Appearance > create stroke > stroke offset (I don't want the stroke to "eat" part of the text), and it looks great **but** I am having some ugly effects with some letters like A, N, etc.

[image]

How can I fill these holes? I tried to play around with many settings but no good results til now.

Also I don't want to make two same texts over each other, one with stroke and one not, because they are hundreds of texts that must be editable and edit two texts each time is not productive.

I'm using Illustrator CS6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offsetting the stroke is probably what causes the problem.
You actually don't need to do so. In the appearance panel just drag and drop your stroke under your fill. Make sure a color is applied to your fill.

[image]